# Sin and cos appeared to represent a inner product of 2 vectors with polar coordinates

Tags: vectors, inner-products, polar-coordinates

[image]

As shown in the above diagram , the inner product of the 2 vectors is given as the formula below.

$$  \boldsymbol{H}\cdot\boldsymbol{M} = \left\{ H_{r}M \cos\left(\phi_{} \right) + H_{\theta_{} }M \sin\left(\phi_{} \right)  \right\}  \tag{1}  $$

Why this equation can be obtained?　Why cosine and sine appeared?

I know the below definitions of a inner product.

$$  \boldsymbol{a}= \left( x_{1},x_{2},x_{3} \right) ~~,~~  \boldsymbol{b}= \left( y_{1},y_{2},y_{3} \right) ~$$

$$~ \boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{b} = \prod_{ i=1 }^{ 3 } x_{i}y_{i} = \left| \left| a \right|  \right| \cdot \left| \left| b \right|  \right| \cos\left(\text{angle between the vectors} \right)   $$

Can I still deduce the equation1 from the above definitons?

Or even a misprint?

Comment: The notation is a bit confusing. Is $M$ a scalar or a vector? And are $(H_r, H_\theta)$ the polar coordinates of $H$?

Comment: $~ \boldsymbol{M} ~$ is a vector. And $~ \left( H_{r},H_{\theta_{} } \right)  ~$ means that $~ \boldsymbol{H} ~$ is composed with polar coordinates.

Comment: We can assume that $~\boldsymbol{M}~$ is a constant vector.